# Adding files outside main directory to python wheel package

Tags: python, python-wheel

I have a folder structure as shown below.

```
folder_1
│   gloabal_vars.py
│
└───folder_2
    │   setup.py
    │
    └───folder_3
        │   info.yaml
        │
        └───folder_4
                file_1.txt
                file_2.txt
```

I want to create a wheel package for folder_2 so that my import statement looks like `import folder_2.folder_3` all the information regarding import is contained in the `info.yaml` file. This info will be used in `setup.py` file. The problem is that, I also want to include `global_variables.py` in this wheel package.

What changes should I do to the `info.yaml` and `setup.py` to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried (from ..top_level_module import some_function) ? In folder_2, create an empty __init__ .py  file and use relative imports to import modules from other folders.

Comment: I want to include ```global_vars.py``` in wheel package. And not to include it separately every time.

Comment: @Utku Can you are talking about the import in program, right? or are you talking about the dynamic imports?